# What is this visual bug with Google Spreadsheet? And how do I fix it?

Tags: google-sheets

This only happens in this one particular spreadsheet, on all tabs. Refresh doesn't work. Restarting the browser doesn't work. Ctrl-F5 doesn't work. Sometimes it doesn't happen after I restart my PC, but once it happens, the only fix is a fresh reboot. What is going on? This doesn't make any sense. All other sheets are fine.

The issue in question:
[image]

Comment: See what happens when you make a copy of this spreadsheet.

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here (or something very similar)!

The problem is that other browsers don't have the same functionality as chrome when using google sheets.